# When is it okay to replace f(n) terms with g(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, discrete-mathematics

So during my lecture my professor demonstrated how to solve this problem...

```
Prove n^2 + 2n + lgn = O(n^2)
```

So for this problem if I'm correct, I can replace lgn and 2n with n^2 
because it grows faster than those terms. After doing that, we'd end up with    `n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2  as our g(n)`

```
0 <= n^2 2n + lgn <= n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2 for all n >= 1
```

However, is this only allowed when proving Big O questions, or can the same methodology be used when trying to prove Big Omega?

So with that being said that leads us to this problem...

```
Prove 2n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n is Big Omega (n^3)
```

For this problem he got rid of -3n^2 completely, and only swapped 2n with n^3.
So after doing all of this g(n) would be this.

```
2n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n >= 2n^3 - n^3 for all n >= 3
```

Why wasn't -3n^2 replaced with n^3?

Comment: You don't *replace* them, you just discard them, because they become overshadowed by the largest term. Your professor has blatantly ignored the *limit definition* of big-O.

Comment: So we basically just keep all the terms that are equal to g(n)?

Comment: You haven't stated what `g(n)` is, but you can get rid of all terms except the fastest growing one, e.g. `n^2 + 2n + lg n --> n^2` (not `4n^2`).

Comment: f(n) =  2n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n  and g(n) = (n^3).  So with this I could keep only 2n^3 and then go from there to prove?

Comment: As I said, only keep the largest term.